# Is there any way to detect who reacted to a message in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am working on a bot and it should send a message, and then stores the first user who reacted to it in a variable.  I tried using `wait_for(reaction_add)` but I am still getting an error!

Comment: Check the answer I left, it should work.
P.S. I tought you were italian  that's why I put "utente" and  "reazione" as variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Event

---

The event should be [`on_reaction_add`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add), and the arguments are `(reaction, user)`.
`reaction` returns a [`discord.Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction) object, `user` returns a `discord.Member` object.

## wait_for

So, you can try something like this:

```
reazione, utente = Bot.wait_for('reaction_add')
```

The `reazione` variabile will contain the `discord.Reaction` object.
The user who reacted is in the `utente` variable.

## discord.Reaction

---

A `discord.Reaction` object also has the `.users()` method, which returns all the users who used the reactions. This may be usefull for you.